Create custom module react native windows
I have a problem. I am creating a native module for React Native Windows and I might not have fully understood how the module registration works.
This is my test1.h
`#pragma once
#include "pch.h"

using namespace winrt;

REACT_MODULE(MyNativeModule);
  struct MyNativeModule
  {

    REACT_METHOD(Add, L"add");
    double Add(double a, double b) noexcept
    {
      double result = a + b;
      return result;
    }
 };`

And this is the ReactPackageProvider.cpp
`#include "pch.h"
#include "ReactPackageProvider.h"
#include "NativeModules.h"
#include "test1.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Microsoft::ReactNative;

namespace winrt::xxxxxxxx::implementation
{

void ReactPackageProvider::CreatePackage(IReactPackageBuilder const &packageBuilder) noexcept
{
    AddAttributedModules(packageBuilder, true);   
}`

But when i call it from react i have undefined
`NativeModules
} from 'react-native';

const { MyNativeModule } = NativeModules;

MyNativeModule.add(20, 40, (result) => {
    console.log(result) // 60
  });`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot to everyone.
